# How to use COALESCE with INTERVAL in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

This is a syntax error, but didn't see what the correct syntax would be.

The goal is to handle the case where days is null.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE created_at > current_date - INTERVAL 'COALESCE(%days%, 999) DAY'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiply `COALESCE(%days%, 999)` to an interval of 1 day:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
WHERE created_at > current_date - COALESCE(%days%, 999) * INTERVAL '1 DAY'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `make_interval()`

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl 
 WHERE created_at > current_date - make_interval(days:=COALESCE(%days%, 999));
```